# "Mount" (run) legacy http handler in Hapi.js

Tags: node.js, http, hapi.js

I did a Node.js meetup presentation and was unable to answer this question. It is still bothering me.

Suppose I have a legacy http application or an Express.js application. It is a function, of the form

```
function legacy_app(request, response) {
  // Handle the request.
}
```

Suppose I adopt Hapi.js for new versions of my application. But I have lots of debugged legacy or upstream code which I wish to integrate into the Hapi application. For example, a legacy vhost will run the legacy version, or it is accessible inside a `/legacy` namespace in the URL.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping existing HTTP node server dispatch function for use as a hapi handler is probably ok but you must add to your hapi_wrap function (at the end):

`reply.close(false);`

so that hapi can finish handling the request without messing with you legacy logic (https://github.com/spumko/hapi/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#replycloseoptions).

Wrapping Express handler/middleware is much more complicated because you are probably relying on some other middleware (e.g. body parser, cookie parse, session, etc.) and using some of the Express decorator that are not part of node (e.g. res.send(), res.json(), etc.).

Comment: Thank you very much! I think if it is very important that it be error-free, I would also consider using Hapi's reverse-proxy support. Yes, it makes the deployment more complex (multiple services listening) however now that I think about it, that is basically the purpose of the proxy feature (or at least one of its purposes).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this is manually. Just directly break the advice in the documentation: pull out the raw request and response objects and pass them to the legacy handler.

```
// An application built with http core.
var http = require('http')
var legacy_server = http.createServer(legacy_handler)
function legacy_handler(request, response) {
  response.end('I am a standard handler\n')
}

// An express application.
var express = require('express')
var express_app = express()
express_app.get('*', function(request, response) {
  response.send('I am an Express app\n')
})

// A Hapi application.
var Hapi = require('hapi')
var server = new Hapi.Server(8080, "0.0.0.0")
server.route({path:'/', method:'*', handler:hapi_handler})
function hapi_handler(request, reply) {
  reply('I am a Hapi handler\n')
}

// Okay, great. Now suppose I want to hook the legacy application into the
// newer Hapi application, for example under a vhost or a /deprecated namespace.
server.route({path:'/legacy', method:'*', handler:hapi_wrap(legacy_handler)})
server.route({path:'/express', method:'*', handler:hapi_wrap(express_app)})

// Convert a legacy http handler into a Hapi handler.
function hapi_wrap(handler) {
  return hapi_handler
  function hapi_handler(request, reply) {
    var req = request.raw.req
    var res = request.raw.res

    reply.close(false)
    handler(req, res)
  }
}

legacy_server.listen(8081)
express_app.listen(8082)
server.start()
```

This seems to work, although I would love if somebody who knew Hapi well could confirm that it is bug-free.

```
$ # Hit the Hapi application
$ curl localhost:8080/
I am a Hapi handler

$ # Hit the http application
$ curl localhost:8081/
I am a standard handler

$ # Hit the Express application
$ curl localhost:8082/
I am an Express app

$ # Hit the http application hosted by Hapi
$ curl localhost:8080/legacy
I am a standard handler

$ # Hit the Express application hosted by Hapi
$ curl localhost:8080/express
I am an Express app
```